# WebSVN + TortoiseSVN

Tags: tortoise-svn

my client gave me the access the the reposotiry (I see it is hosted using WebSVN) but, when I try to do the checkout using the TortoiseSVN, I'm getting the error

```
Unable to connect to a repository at URL
 'https://svn.the-site.com/'
The OPTIONS response did not include the requested activity-collection-set;
 this often means that the URL is not WebDAV-enabled
```

I can't find any fix of that problem, any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have **only** WebSVN frontend, you **can't get repository URL** from URL in WebSVN - you have to ask WebSVN admin about *real* URLs